# how to find project server 2013 display version with powershell?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

how to find project server 2013 display version with powershell?

Can you please advise me how to get with powershell or stsadm commands.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: what u mean by display version?

Comment: project server 2013 build version

Answer (score 0):

run this pwoershell in windows powershell console:

```
ASNP Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

(Get-SPFarm).Products
```

if then match the GUID with following

Project Server 2013: `35466B1A-B17B-4DFB-A703-F74E2A1F5F5E`

Project Server 2013 Preview `BC7BAF08-4D97-462C-8411-341052402E71`

http://blog.fpweb.net/how-to-find-your-sharepoint-version-in-ten-seconds-flat-with-powershell/#.WRn-0-XysdU

https://nearbaseline.com/2010/12/how-to-check-the-version-of-sharepoint-project-server-installed/

You can check it from central admin 
To see which build your products are :

- Open Central Administration
- Click on Upgrade and Migration
- Click Check Product and patch installation status
  (/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx)

Or use this powershell `(Get-SPFarm).BuildVersion`

Comment: The second url is not working could you please post me the what content you have in it...the above I tried not the exact I am looking for...

Comment: what u looking for? 2nd is talking about the check the build version...what cu installed on the server?

Comment: Ex for :(Get-SPfarm)buildversion the same way I need for project server latest version by using powershell commands.

Comment: (Get-SPFarm).BuildVersion this command will give u the build number....

Comment: can you provide any other way to check project server version?

Comment: central admin, you can check it...i just edit my answer pleae check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58810/discussion-between-santhosh-kumar-and-waqas-sarwar-mvp).